# How can I make 2 centered divs with left aligned text?

Tags: css, sass, bulma

I'm using Bulma + SCSS, and I'm trying to make 2 centered columns (like `mx-auto`) with a bit of padding in between (`p-3`, for example). How can I do this?
(sorry for not having any code to show)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWKhj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you asked for

```
<section style="width: 100%; display:flex; justify-content: center;" >
 <section style="display:flex; gap: 0 100px;">
  <div>
   Box 1
  </div>
  <div>
   Box 2
  </div>
 </section>
</section>
```

the gap property doesn't work on safari and some other browsers so you can use margin or padding to seprate the divs

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: please tick this answer if it helped

Comment: It makes you wait 10 minutes before you can accept an answer :)